# A special generalized eigenvalue problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics, generalized-eigenvector

I have to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem, $A x = \lambda B x $. Here $A,B$ are both $n\times n $ symmetric and in particular, $B$ is positive definite. I just need the smallest generalized eigenvalue.

Now, suppose that $B $ has the simple form $B = I + uu^T $. Similarly, $A$ is also simple and its action on a vector $x$ can be done in $O(n)$ operations.

For such special cases, is there a particular fast algorithm?

Comment: Can you find the largest eigenvalues of $A^{-1}B$?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that $A$ is also simple? Do you mean that $A = I + vv^T$ for some vector $v$?

Comment: @CarlChristian  Not that simple. It is $A = H + v_1 v_1^T + v_2 v_3^T + v_3 v_2^T. $ Here $H$ is very sparse.

Comment: I think that the TraceMIN algorithm using the Sherman-Morrison formula to solve linear systems with coefficient matrix  is worth trying.